# Justify that at least three students have completed the session with the same set of grades

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Question:

> There are 41 students per year. All students during the exam session passed 3 subjects. The grading scale (for each subject) was four-point: A, B, C, U. Justify that at least three students have completed the session with the same set of grades (there doesn't have to be compliance in individual subjects) it is enough if, for example, students have A, A, C (possibly from different subjects).

What I did:
I put the two variables in the question into sets A (set of all students), B(possibiliies for grade distributions):

> |A|=41, |B|=20

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  You (correctly) remark that there are $20$ possible grades (viewed as a $4-$tuple of non-negative integers that sum to $3$), and $20<41$.  Something seems strange though, since $20$ is so much smaller than $41$.

Comment: I think the OP must mean _prove_, not _justify_.

Comment: Oh, you said three students.  That makes more sense.  as there are $20$ possible grades, if exactly $2$ students had each possible grade that would account for $40$ students.  The last one must make a triple.

Comment: Phrased differently..  Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{20}$ be the number of students having each possible grade (so $a_1$ is, say, the number of students who got straight $A's$ and some on).  Clearly $\sum a_i=41$.  If each $a_i≤2$, we'd have $\sum a_i≤40$, a contradiction.

Comment: pigeonhole principle